# Interacting particle systems

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am novice to interacting particle systems. I was reading a book on the same. The book gives an example of a population system of $n(t)$ particles at time $t$. The births rates are $\lambda$ births and death rates are $1$. How does this translate to transition probabilities? The book says $P(n,t;n-1,t-1) = \lambda \Delta t$ and $P(n,t; n+1, t-1) = n \Delta t$. I did not quite follow how the transition rates are the same as birth and death rates specified. Is this by just definition?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your relationships for the Ps. Please state exactly what the P probabilities are. Are they the probabilities of exactly plus or minus 1 change in the population over very short time interval $\Delta t$? If so it seems the $(t - 1)$ specifications for the Ps should be $(t - \Delta t$)?

More generally, the change in the population is given by ${{dn} \over {dt}} = (\lambda - 1) n$.  This is similar to the relationship for a radionuclide being both produced and decaying; for example see the text Nuclear Physics by Kaplan.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I got it. They are all rates, i.e. over a short interval of time $\Delta t$

Comment: Yes, delta t is infinitesimally small.